# Javascript office api insert image in powerpoint

Tags: javascript, openxml, office-js, openoffice-api

I'm trying to insert a image in powerpoint using javascript office api. I tryed to return a XElement with the image and insert it but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible using

```
Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(result, {
                            coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Image,
                            imageLeft: 50,
                            imageTop: 50,
                            imageWidth: 100,
                            imageHeight: 100
                        });
```

but Office.CoercionType.Image is available only for Office 365 ProPlus version 16.0.6741.2014